# Popup a compulsive window that the user can only interact with by Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, popup

So compulsive window here means like, I currently have interface(1) with a button, I click the button and it gives me a popup. I want this popup to be the only window that the user can interactive, so the user in this case cannot interact with interface(1). Think it like you are saving a Word doc, when you choose the file location to save this Word doc, you cannot modify the content of this Word doc. And that file saving window is what I want.

Currently I have a custom popup:

```
public class InputPopup {
    private int closeflag;
    private JFrame popup;
    ...

    public int getCloseflag() {return closeflag;}

    public void close(){
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void run() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                popup.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this is what I did in the button listener

```
InputPopup popup = new InputPopup(wordLabel.getText(), description.getText());
popup.run();
int flag = popup.getCloseflag();
while (flag != 1) {
    flag = popup.getCloseflag();
}
popup.close();
```

Of course that does not work. Anyone has any idea on how to achieve that effect?

Comment: You have two solutions that you can trigger when you show your popup window: 1) Place a [glass pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) over top of your JFrame/UI that consumes any interaction, or 2) Try `yourJFrame.setEnabled​(false);` to disable interaction with your JFrame and contents.

Comment: factss!!! if only there were a double upvote on comments. Take a look at what sorifiend linked there and what sorifiend is saying.

Comment: *Think it like you are saving a Word doc, when you choose the file location to save this Word doc,* -  You would use a modal JDialog.  *And that file saving window is what I want.* - Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).

Comment: You're looking for a "modal" dialog or window